# VBA IF Statement within specified time and Range

Tags: excel, vba

trying to figure out how to write `If` statement in VBA where

```
IF RANGE() > 2000 AND WITHINTIME SAY 10s RANGE() < 2000 THEN
```

Don't know if this is possible but if it is would be very helpful Thanks.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean. What's the "2000" bit? And where you say "RANGE()" are you wanting to do an if condition on a bunch of cells at once or just one cell? (which is OK, that's still technically a range... i just assume where you write range() you meant a range of more than one cells?)

Comment: Sorry I guess I need to add more clarification. If Range("CAD_PL") > 2000 And Range("CAD_POSITION") > 0 Then
            QueueNum = API.AddQueuedOrder("CAD", Abs(cadpos), 0, API.SELL, API.MKT)
            Sleep (200)

Comment: Thats what I have so far but I want to add the time and if range("CAD_PL") < 2000

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest "DateAdd" as a useful function that might help... though the question is not very well thought out. I'm not sure what "2000" has to do with anything?

```
If _
    (rgCell.value < DateAdd("s", 10, TestTime)) AND _
    (rgCell.value > DateAdd("s", -10, TestTime)) Then

    '... Do stuff

End If
```

Comment: Sorry 2000 is a value in a listed cell that is variable so what I want to add is if goes < 2000 then it will carry out an action.

Comment: ok I think i get you... so you can just add a couple more "and" conditions to the if statement and should be ok?